# Select specific part of a attribute and assign it to a variable

Tags: xslt

I want to select specific part of a attribute and assign it to a variable.

Input :

```
<p anepane="swedd" conref="../../go_ref/Disti_didin#Disti_didin/k_irl_oi_2222"/>
```

There are lot of `<p>` in input. In that all `<p>` last part starts with `p_frm`. So I want common template to select `p_frm_l1_los_246` from `@conref` and assign to to a variable.

Tried code :

```
<xsl:template match="p[@conref]">
    <xsl:variable name="aaa" select="self:p"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Above tried code is not working. Help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
<xsl:template match="p[substring-after(substring-after(@conref,'#'),'/') = 'p_frm_l1_los_246']">
    <xsl:variable name="aaa" select="@conref"/>
</xsl:template>
```

It selects the whole value of `p/@conref` which ends with `p_frm_l1_los_246`.

> ../../page_references/where_used_breadcrumbs.dita#where_used_breadcrumbs/p_frm_l1_los_246